# Group by terms and get count of nested array property?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I would like to get the count from a document series where an array item matches some value.

I have documents like these:

```
{
    "Name": "jason",
    "Todos": [{
        "State": "COMPLETED"
        "Timer": 10
        },{
        "State": "PENDING"
        "Timer": 5
    }]
}

{
    "Name": "jason",
    "Todos": [{
        "State": "COMPLETED"
        "Timer": 5
        },{
        "State": "PENDING"
        "Timer": 2
    }]
}

{
    "Name": "martin",
    "Todos": [{
        "State": "COMPLETED"
        "Timer": 15
        },{
        "State": "PENDING"
        "Timer": 10
    }]
}
```

I would like to count how many documents I have where they have any Todos with COMPLETED State. And group by Name.

So from the above I would need to get:
jason: 2
martin: 1

Usually I do this with a term aggregation for the Name, and an other sub aggregation for other items:

```
"aggs": {
    "statistics": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "Name"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "test": {
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                                "match_phrase": {
                                    "SomeProperty.keyword": {
                                        "query": "THEVALUE"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
```

But not sure how to do this here as I have items in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch has no problem with arrays because in fact it [flattens them by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/nested.html#_how_arrays_of_objects_are_flattened):

> Arrays of inner object fields do not work the way you may expect. Lucene has no concept of inner objects, so Elasticsearch flattens object hierarchies into a simple list of field names and values.

So a query like the one you posted will do. I would use [`term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-term-query.html) query for [`keyword` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/keyword.html), though:

```
POST mytodos/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "how many completed": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "Todos.State": "COMPLETED"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am assuming your mapping looks something like this:

```
PUT mytodos/_mappings
{
  "properties": {
    "Name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "Todos": {
      "properties": {
        "State": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "Timer": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

The example documents that you posted will be transformed internally into something like this:

```
{
  "Name": "jason",
  "Todos.State": ["COMPLETED", "PENDING"],
  "Todos.Timer": [10, 5]
}
```

However, if you need to query for `Todos.State` *and* `Todos.Timer`, for example, filter for those `"COMPLETED"` but only with `Timer > 10`, it will not be possible with such mapping because Elasticsearch forgets the link between fields of object array items.

In this case you would need to use something like [`nested` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/nested.html) for such arrays, and query them with special [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

Hope that helps!